# FlowDocument - Prevent breaks between paragraphs

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument that contains lists with a header:

```
Header 1           -   Item 2
-   Item 1         
-   Item 2         Header 3
-   Item 3         -   Item 1
                   -   etc.
Header 2
-   Item 1
```

I want to prevent page/column breaks so that the layout will be like this:

```
Header 1           Header 2
-   Item 1         -   Item 1
-   Item 2         -   Item 2
-   Item 3         
                   Header 3
```

I don't want the List including the header to split over mulitple columns or pages. How can I achieve this?

The layout is currently as  follows:

- Paragraph (header)
- List

  - List Item

Comment: Just a guess: did you try the [BreakColumnBefore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.breakcolumnbefore.aspx) property? This List would have to be inside the Paragraph.

Comment: @Clemens I'm sorry, not trying to insert breaks, just prevent a paragraph as a whole from breaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the [KeepTogether](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.keeptogether.aspx) property would prevent column or page breaking inside a paragraph.

Comment: But I cannot insert a list into a paragraph :( Trying to make something work with ItemsControl.

Comment: @Bas You're right, the flow document model doesn't like what you want to do.